# Generate Libc Signatures using IDA sigmake

Tags: linux, reverse-engineering, glibc, ida

I want to generate libc signatures using IDA sigmake for GNU/Linux 2.6.24 - 64bit. Is there a location from where I can directly download libc.a corresponding to the GNU/Linux 2.6.24 64-bit version.

Where ever I looked on internet, only glibc source code is available and I am unable to locate binaries for Glibc.

Could someone please suggest where can I download direct Glibc binary libc.a for GNU/Linux 2.6.24 64-bit release.

Comment: I am actually reverse-engineering a 64-bit binary that is built for GNU/Linux 2.6.24 and the binary is stripped off for symbols.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a location from where I can directly download libc.a corresponding to the GNU/Linux 2.6.24 64-bit version.

There is no such thing as `libc.a` corresponding to `GNU/Linux 2.6.24 64-bit version`: different versions of GLIBC could be used on a system using `Linux 2.6.24` kernel (and conversely, a single version of GLIBC could be used across different kernel versions).

In addition, each distribution compiles its own GLIBC, so you need to find one that matches *your* distribution.

Usually `libc.a` is included in `libc-dev` or `libc6-dev` or similarly named package (package name again varies between different distributions).